# Updating UIAlertView Message dynamically and newline character issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I need to display multiple lines of text in the message of my UIAlertView. I have tried adding a '\n', but it has no effect. It still displays: "This is an examp....".

HOWEVER, if I turn my iPhone to landscape mode it displays the message as I intend it to. And then if I switch BACK to portrait mode it displays correctly there as well.

Update: After further consideration, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I am updating the current message with a new (and much longer) string. I have already called "show" on the alert view, and am trying to update the message. Perhaps something needs to be redrawn? Like i said before, it displays correctly if I change orientations (doesn't matter which orientation I start in, i still have the same problem). i have already tried "setNeedsDisplay" and "setNeedsLayout".

Comment: why are you changing the message AFTER showing the dialog ? Of course your problem is there

Comment: I'm using the dialog to keep the user updated on the progress of a task. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I believe updating the alert view's text while it's being displayed is wrong, the only way I see to change it is this way

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"this is a message\nthis is a new line text" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"test button",nil];  
[alert show];

//set the new message
NSString *newMessage = [NSString stringWithString:@"Test\nWith a new message with\ncustom new line string\n and a lot\n of new lines\n Yep"];
[alert setMessage:newMessage];

//get the original alert Frame
CGRect alertFrame = alert.frame;
//get the alert view Label
UILabel *alertLabel = [alert.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
//and get the original frame position
CGRect alertLabelFrame = alertLabel.frame;

//see how much space we are needing for the new message and adjust
int heightChange = [newMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(alertLabelFrame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height - alertLabelFrame.size.height;

alertFrame.size.height += heightChange;
//adjust the Label height to the new height
alertLabelFrame.size.height += heightChange;

//adjust the frame and elements with an animation for smoothness
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0.4 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn) animations:^{
    [alert setFrame:alertFrame];           
    alertLabel.frame = alertLabelFrame;
    //move any buttons
    for (UIView *subView in alert.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            //this is a button move it
            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)subView;
            CGRect alertButtonFrame = button.frame;
            //adjust button Y position to the new height
            alertButtonFrame.origin.y += heightChange-5;
            button.frame = alertButtonFrame;
        }
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: im working on something like this above right now, but a little different....would you be able to help me out in chat real quick?

Comment: @KeeanoMartin I would suggest you just ask it on SO as a new question and I or someone else can reply

Answer (score 3):

For newline use the \n newline character in your text like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"this is a message\nthis is a new line text" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Even with setMessage this works:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert setMessage:@"this is\na test"];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: If I do : [myAlertView setMessage:@"This is my\nmessage"] it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Did you try copying pasting what I wrote? I just tried it in the simulator and it worked perfectly... \r\n could also be given a try

Answer (score 0):

Use '\r' symbol. It should break line properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple code to resize the messages in an alert. Note that the alert's frame needs to be large enough. You can pad the initial alert with a few newlines.

```
for (UILabel *l in alertView.subviews){
    if ([l isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        float w = l.frame.size.width;
        [l setNumberOfLines:0];
        [l sizeToFit];
        CGRect r = l.frame;
        r.size.width = w;
        l.frame = r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Create your own AlertView Category.

AlertWithBlock.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIAlertView (AlertWithBlock)

- (void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock;

- (void)setDelegateBlock:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock;


+ (void)alertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title buttonTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle message:(NSString *)message;

+ (UIAlertView *)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString   *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles delegate:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegate;

@end
```

Comment: #import "UIAlertView+AlertWithBlock.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: Import it in Controller .m file

Comment: How to call from controller.[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Info!" buttonTitle:@"Cancle" message:@"Network Error !"];

    [UIAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"This is a message" cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@[@"Yes",@"No"] delegate:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
        [self showButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
    }];
    
    }];

Comment: I don’t know a lot about Objective-C, but this is clearly not what you have to write in that file. Could you improve formatting so it becomes more readable? Especially take care of using code blocks (if that is actual code) by indenting the code lines by 4 spaces.