# Is it possible to dynamically change the message of a UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

In my app a user can create a new file. I use a UIAlertView with style `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` to prompt the user to enter a name for the new file. Of course, I want to make sure that the file name entered in the text field does not already exist.

So whenever the user changes the text in the alert view's text field I want to test if a file with that name exists and if so notify the user by setting the alert view's message:

```
alertView.message = @"File exists! Please enter a different name.";
```

In all other cases, when a file with that name does not exist, I do not want to show a message at all. I have tried several things but it seems like the only way to achieve this goal is to use a space character in the latter case:

```
if (fileExists) {
    alertView.message = @"File exists! Please enter a different name.";
} else {
    alertView.message = @" ";
}
```

The disadvantage here is that the alert view will show an empty line in most cases (when no such with that name exists) and I would like to avoid that. How can I do that?
Or is there another maybe better way to notify the user?

Answer (score 1):

**Create alertView**

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[self getAlert] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
```

**getAlert**

```
- (NSString *)getAlert {
    if(true) {
        return @"String 1";
    } else {
        return @"String 2";
    }
    return @"null";
}
```

We are calling a method to get a string and in that method we can create our conditional statements to see what string we want to use.

Comment: That looks like a very elegant solution at first. The problem is: I want to change the alert view's message depending on the alert view's text field content. When I use a method `getAlert` in the alert view's `init`-method the alert view hasn't been initialized yet so there is no way to pass the alert view's text field to the alert view method.

Comment: @Mischa Oh... I completely mis-read your question, let me come up with an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your task in a new thread by calling [self performSelectorInBackground:withObject:] and update UIAlertView text by calling [self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]. I just succeeded.

This topic may also be useful, introducing calculate and adjust alertView frame with an animation for smoothness
[Updating UIAlertView Message dynamically and newline character issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236167/updating-uialertview-message-dynamically-and-newline-character-issue)