# How to show time in UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, uialertview, uialertcontroller

In my app I'm implementing audio recorder. Everything working fine.

But when user taps on record button I have to show `UIAlertView` with time in seconds.

So that user can easily understand like recording.

I don't have any idea about this.

How can I do this or suggest me any other idea please.

Comment: the time needs to keep on moving, is it? or just a static time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236167/updating-uialertview-message-dynamically-and-newline-character-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8, now you can use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of alert.

If the seconds are statics you can use

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“Your title string”
                                                               message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“Seconds: %f”,yourSecondsVariable];
                                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil)
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I think that you can use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` (of `NSDate`) to initialize your `yourSecondsVariable`.

Comment: plus 1 for `UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8`

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question at all. It's just a standard snippet of how to present an alert controller. The question clearly states "How to show *time*" - time is dynamic and changes all the *time*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time to be dynamic (continually updating) then this should get you started.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *timeLabel;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)timer {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Time" message:@"\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    self.timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 260, 50)];
    self.timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        self.timeLabel.text = [NSDate date].description;
    }];

    [alert.view addSubview:self.timeLabel];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```